# DAX: Subtract X Years/Days/Months from NOW()

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'd like to create a dynamic date table, the date range is NOW - 3yr to NOW.  How is this done in DAX?

I know how to use the calendar function, and have used the MIN and MAX on a table of invoices to get the start/end dates, but now need to get the current date -3 years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out, I used this:

```
Date Filter = CALENDAR(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()) - 3,MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY())),today())
```